# Disable Chrome search on invalid urls

Tags: google-chrome, search, chromium

How can I prevent Chrome/Chromium from searching via the address bar unless I explicitly start with "?" or any other keyword?

I'm trying to avoid searches where I'd rather have an error message stating invalid url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new search engine in preferences, set URL to %s and use it as the default one - this will produce the message you want instead of actually searching.

Comment: Nice, although I cannot use Ctrl+K anymore it is only one more character typing for search: "Ctrl+L g <search>"

Answer (score 0):

More likely it's your ISP or DNS that redirect if you type in a invalid URL. If you type an URL that is invalid you should get this message: **This webpage is not available**.You might get this too: **Oops! Google Chrome could not find....**

Comment: You are talking about non existing URLs(domain names), my question is about invald urls. For example "invalid url"